# Как деплоить Java приложение в AWS ElasticBeanstalk используя Bitbucket pipelines?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pipelines

Как деплоить Java приложение в AWS ElasticBeanstalk используя Bitbucket pipelines ? Я нашел тут пример как это сделать. Сформировал *yml* файл для пайплайна. Переписал *py script* под себя. Все проходит окей при сборке проекта но на последнем шаге скрипт выдает ошибку. Как это исправить?

**YML File**

```
image: openkbs/jre-mvn-py3

pipelines:
 branches:
  master:
   - step:
      caches:
        - maven
        - node
      script:
        - mvn clean install
        - apt-get update
        - apt-get -y install python-pip
        - pip install boto3
        - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=KEY
        - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=KEY
        - export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=REGION
        - python beanstalk_deploy.py
```

**Python Script**
[Source](https://trinket.io/python/fb718b87ec)

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "beanstalk_deploy.py", line 107, in 
>       main()
>
> File "beanstalk_deploy.py", line 99, in main
>       if not create_new_version():
>
> File "beanstalk_deploy.py", line 56, in create_new_version
>       Process=True
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
>       return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 586, in _make_api_call
>       api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 641, in _convert_to_request_dict
>       api_params, operation_model)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/validate.py", line 291, in serialize_to_request
>       raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
>   botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
>
> Invalid type for parameter SourceBundle.S3Bucket, value: None, type: , valid types: